# Object doesn't Support Property or Method 'replace'

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am getting a strange error in my javascript code.

Here is the code sample

```
function FetchData()
{
var selValue=$("select[id$=ddlComponents]").val()
    var param=$.param({ID:selValue});

    var method="proxy.aspx/GetComponentsValuesAgainstOilValue";

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: method,
    data: param,
    contentType: "application/json",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(response) {

    if (response.replace(/"/g, '') == '{d:[]}') 
    {
         response = eval('(' + response + ')').d;
     }

    },
    error: function(xhr,error,status)
    {   
        alert(error);
    }
  });
```

}

It gives me an error at following line of code

```
if (response.replace(/"/g, '') == '{d:[]}') 
    {
         response = eval('(' + response + ')').d;
    }
```

object does not support property or function 'replace'. But replace function is working with string variables otherwise.

My JQuery ver is 1.6.4

Please help.

Thanks
vivek

Answer (score 5):

`response` is already an object. You don't need to do any JSON parsing on your own.

Answer (score 2):

The type of response is clearly not an object of the type string. Try to parse it as a string or look what's inside the object that is currently being returned and use that in a proper way. In other words...see what your method "GetComponentsValuesAgainstOilValue" is returning to the client. That's probably what is in your response object at the moment (in JSON).

Answer (score 1):

The data parameter taken by success callback is formatted according to the dataType parameter. In your case - "json", so your data is an object.

Comment: @Baszz :The response returned by my function is a List<Custom Class>

Answer (score 0):

Some versions of JQuery doesn't support the method. U need to get the following versions of JQuery

```
<link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```